# Allow second message only after the first one is received

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to combine 2 Firebase Cloud messaging. I combined 2 projects and each have its own firebase messaging. I did not import as module, i just created a new package instead. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
I tried "if else", else and many other combination. Please help, been at it for a week and search many forums to find answers to combine 2 firebase messaging.

//from MyFirebaseMessaging class

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        
        //copied from second project

        if(remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
            //Log.d("EDMTDEV", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Map<String,String> data =  remoteMessage.getData(); // Get data from notification :(
            String customer = data.get("customer");
            String lat = data.get("lat");
            String lng=data.get("lng");


            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CustomerCall.class);
            intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
            intent.putExtra("lng", lng);
            intent.putExtra("customer", customer);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
        
        // second message after the first one above  "CustomerCall.class is active. this is a reply when a button is pressed on the above activity above has started, I DO NOT WANT IT TO START, only if a button is pressed on the above activity "CustomerCall.class"  //


        if(remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
            Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String title = data.get("title");
            final String message = data.get("message");

            if (title.equals("Cancel")) {

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyFirebaseMessaging.this)
                        .sendBroadcast(new Intent("cancel_request"));

            } else if (title.equals("Arrived")) {
                showArrivedNotification(message);
            } else if (title.equals("DropOff")) {
                openRateActivity(message);
            }
        }

    }
```

// this is from CustomerCall.class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_call);

        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecline);

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(customerId))
                    cancelBooking(customerId);
                finish();
            }
        });

}

private void cancelBooking(String customerId) {
        Token2 token2 = new Token2(customerId);
        Map<String,String> content = new HashMap<>();
        content.put("title","Cancel");
        content.put("message", "Driver has cancelled your request");
        DataMessage2 dataMessage2 = new DataMessage2(token2.getToken(),content);

        mFCMService.sendMessage(dataMessage2)
                .enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponse2>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<FCMResponse2> call, Response<FCMResponse2> response) {
                        if (response.body().success == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(CustomerCall.this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<FCMResponse2> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("EDMTLOG",t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: What is your issue here? does any of them work? have got a specific error? at what point are you now?

Comment: i am trying to combine 2 firebase messages.. the first marked " //copied from second project works " and the second is below it.

Comment: i am trying to combine 2 firebase messages.. the first marked " //copied from second project works "is the only one that get call. Sending device sends a message to receiving device which opens up custommer call activity. Receiving device which has custommer call activity opened, is able to reply with the second part of the code upon pressing the cancel button back to sending device.. the reply is suppose to be "Driver has cancelled your request". but when you press the cancel button, the first custommer activity gets called again on the sending device. How do i reply with the second part

Comment: this is reply code

Comment: if(remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
            Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String title = data.get("title");
            final String message = data.get("message");

            if (title.equals("Cancel")) {

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

Comment: like a friend request with yes or no as reply

Comment: i fixed it!!! woohoo by changing the first message to if(remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("customer"))